# Reply-destination with CacheConnectionFactory in Spring Integration

Tags: spring-integration

I have written an jms outbound gateway to send/receive messages synchronously and i am also using CachingConnectionFactory(with sessionCacheSize=5 ). Now spring integration manual says it can cause OutOfMemory error because it creates new consumer with a new selector...
And manual suggests to use  instead but that will make message reception as asynchronous.

Can anyone please provide more insight of in what scenarios reply-destination with CacheConnectionFactory would result in OutOfMemory error and if this is not recommended then how to make message reception synchronous?

Config

```
<int-jms:outbound-gateway
            connection-factory="myCacheConnectionFactory"
            receive-timeout="5000"
            reply-channel="emailChannel" 
            reply-destination="responseQueue" 
            request-channel="requestMsgChannel" 
            request-destination="requestQueue">
</int-jms:outbound-gateway>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the [caution in the documentation explains the problem quite clearly](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/jms.html#jms-outbound-gateway).

The consumer is cached and each one has a different (unique) message selector so can't be reused.

As the caution says, turn off caching consumers in the CCF, or use a `<reply-listener/>` instead.

Comment: Is this problem only with consumers or with producers also, because i also see different producer object for every send ?

Comment: No, producers are only cached by destination so you shouldn't see them growing (unless `cacheProducers` is false - default is true); consumers are cached by destination and selector. If you turn on TRACE level logging you will get full details of the cache management.

Comment: Bear in mind that the default session cache size is 1 so you might see new producers being created if you have concurrent requests; considter increasing the cache size - see the javadocs for more information.